# SocketException, connect reset by peer. Weird behaviour when heartbeating server

Tags: java, android, socketexception, heartbeat

Working on a client-server android application. The clients are polling the `bufferedinputstream (in)` for server messages, meanwhile also repeatedly checking if server is reachable so they can terminate instantly when server goes offline.

```
try {
while (true) {
    if (MainActivity.in.available() > 0) {
        message = MainActivity.readInput();
        break;
    }
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
} catch (IOException e) {Log.e("myoutput", e.toString()); serverOffline = true; } //server probably offline?
catch (InterruptedException e2) {}
```

On one of my test devices (android 2.2) this works as I thought, as soon as I close down the server the `IOException` is triggered. Although on my second test device (android 4.3) the `IOException` is not triggered (compling with API 8). But I'm starting to think this is not a device thing as I tried running both API 8 and 18 in the emulator and it didn't trigger.

Any ideas?

*I'm probably not providing all essential information to get any help from here, please let me know if so and I'll provide!*

Comment: if remote server is closed, in.available maybe get -1, then the code go into infinite loop. you can try to print in.available value to log.

Comment: I checked if in.available ever got -1, nope